# Vote arrow tooltips are wrong for Collectives Articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tooltips, collectives

Consider [this article on the Google Cloud Collective as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android).

When hovering my mouse pointer over the upvote button, I get the pop-up:

> Mark this post as useful and clear

[image]

When hovering my mouse pointer over the downvote button, I get the same pop-up:

> Mark this post as useful and clear

[image]

I hope one of those is wrong.

Comment: I wonder if this will be fixed by changing the tooltip or removing the downvote button.

Comment: For the downvote button tooltip I propose: "Gotcha!!!"

Comment: @JeanneDark another option: just make the down arrow also do an upvote. Now the tooltip matches.

Comment: "Click here if you don't want to leave a comment"

Comment: @CodyGray you're kidding me .... that is probably the solution to a lot of contention ....

Comment: "Would you like to mark this post as useful and clear or as clear and useful? You certainly have the freedom of choice." 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for logging this bug. The developers have been made aware and will prioritize when they get in today.

**Update 2021-08-12**

This is updated and fixed

Comment: Maybe a better approach is tagging the question as [meta-tag:status-planned]

Comment: I've added the tag, @rene. Good tip for the future!

Comment: Added status-review to trigger some internal systems :), in 5 minutes it can change to status-planned

Comment: Looks like it's in Jira so I've updated the tags for you. :)